# Separate bar in chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts, histogram

I would like to show in every bin of the histogram, the 3 bars separated, so that it does not overlap. My code is this:

```py
face = io.imread('images/face.png')

red_chanel = face[:,:,0]
green_chanel = face[:,:,1]
blue_chanel = face[:,:,2]

red_chanel = red_chanel.astype('float')
green_chanel = green_chanel.astype('float')
blue_chanel = blue_chanel.astype('float')
face = face.astype('float')

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(ncols = 1, figsize = (20, 5))

hstred=exposure.histogram(red_chanel, nbins=28)
hstgreen=exposure.histogram(green_chanel, nbins=28)
hstblue=exposure.histogram(blue_chanel, nbins=28)

ax1.bar(list(range(28)), hstred[0], align='edge')
ax1.bar(list(range(28)), hstgreen[0], align='edge')
ax1.bar(list(range(28)), hstblue[0], align='edge')

plt.show()
```

[image: Python Code]

How can I separate the bars?

Comment: Can you please add the code in the text form?

Comment: yes, I just added it

Comment: Added an answer. Let me know if it works for you. If it does please consider accepting/check-marking the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can shift the x-axis for 2nd and 3rd barplot and play with bar `width` a little. In the end, change the `xticks`.

```
import numpy as np
ax1.bar(np.arange(28), hstred[0], align='edge', width=0.3)
#shifting the xaxis
ax1.bar(np.arange(28)+0.3, hstgreen[0], align='edge', width=0.3)
ax1.bar(np.arange(28)+0.6, hstblue[0], align='edge', width=0.3)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0,28)+0.3, np.arange(0,28)) #resetting the ticks
```

Here is an example:

```
x1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y1 = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6]
y2 = [4, 4, 2, 2, 2]
y3 = [3, 4, 6, 7, 8]

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(x1,y1,width=0.3)
ax.bar(np.array(x1)+0.3,y2,width=0.3) 
ax.bar(np.array(x1)+0.6,y3,width=0.3)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0,6)+0.3, np.arange(0,6))
plt.show()
```

**Output**:

[image]